# GCP CDN cache-miss granularity

Tags: caching, google-cloud-platform, google-cloud-cdn

I'm trying to make an accurate estimate of CDN usage on Google Cloud Platform but am not sure about the fill costs.

Fill costs are incurred on a cache miss and the data is gotten from origin or another cache. What's not specifically mentioned is how granular a "cache" miss is. That is - is it a cache miss for the region? zone? POP? node?

With an international distribution this could be make a huge difference in estimation.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I asked Google support directly on this one and got back that cache fills occur in each "cache site." Or as they put it:

> Cache fill is counted for each caching sites since cache fill occured between one cache location to another cache location.

The updated list of cache sites/locations is [in their documentation](https://cloud.google.com/cdn/docs/locations).

At the time of writing that means a hypothetical max of 81 cache fills for a given result (not including expiring or being pushed out of the cache and re-filling etc.) - presuming your content is requested from each of these location as the cache is [only filled when requested](https://cloud.google.com/cdn/docs/overview#fill-and-egress).

Answer (score 0):

According to the official documentation, cache fill charges vary based on source and destination. Source is the region of the origin server or, in the case of cache-to-cache cache fill, the region of the source cache. Destination is a geographic area determined by client IP address.
[link](https://cloud.google.com/cdn/pricing#cache_fill_pricing_tables)

Comment: What you say is correct, but it does not say the max number of cache fills you could have. I asked google directly and answered the original question with it separately.